# How to fix undefined reference to glibc 2.4 symbol when linking Rust static library for musl target?

Tags: c++, linux, rust, cross-compiling, musl

I'm trying to use a Rust library (via cbindgen) with my C++ program on a musl target. I used [cross](https://crates.io/crates/cross) to cross compile. The exact error is:

```
/mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/compiled-binaries/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/11.2.0/../../../../arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd: /mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/inkbox-toreader/libs/Libretranslate-rs-to-cpp/lib//libLibretranslate_rs_to_cpp.a(Libretranslate_rs_to_cpp-da46da90a85dac4d.Libretranslate_rs_to_cpp.a677ed00b91c84d4-cgu.0.rcgu.o): in function `rust_eh_personality':
/rustc/03a119b0b0e310d22d94399b24ed030056050f13/library/std/src/sys/personality/gcc.rs:99: multiple definition of `rust_eh_personality'; /mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/inkbox-toreader/libs/libreader-rs/lib//libreader_rs.a(reader_rs-08f466727572406f.reader_rs.16ecb517c7176846-cgu.0.rcgu.o):/rustc/03a119b0b0e310d22d94399b24ed030056050f13/library/std/src/sys/personality/gcc.rs:99: first defined here
/mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/compiled-binaries/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/11.2.0/../../../../arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd: /mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/inkbox-toreader/libs/Libretranslate-rs-to-cpp/lib//libLibretranslate_rs_to_cpp.a(Libretranslate_rs_to_cpp-da46da90a85dac4d.Libretranslate_rs_to_cpp.a677ed00b91c84d4-cgu.0.rcgu.o): undefined reference to symbol 'clock_gettime@@GLIBC_2.4'
/mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/compiled-binaries/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/11.2.0/../../../../arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd: /home/build/inkbox/compiled-binaries/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot//lib/librt.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It happens when I try to create the C++ program after successfully compiling the Rust library.

I had a similar problem (also glibc) in the first library when I added because I had `[lib] crate-type = ["rlib"]` (I have there only `"staticlib"` now, I link those libraries statically) to make integration tests to work (solution from [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/does-crate-type-has-effect-on-integration-test/76634)).

However, this time I don't have any tests but a lot more libraries: openssl vendored and some hacky tokio futures:

```ini
futures = "0.3"
futures-executor = { version = "0.3", features = ["thread-pool"] }
libretranslate = { path = "lib-rs/libretranslate-rs" }
openssl = { version = '0.10', features = ["vendored"] }
```

Some extra info:

- [Here is a readelf](http://pkgs-inkbox.duckdns.org:25560/misc/readelf.txt) of the Rust library (it's 250Mb because it's debug build to include all info).
- [Here is the repository](https://github.com/Szybet/Libretranslate-rs-to-cpp) with the code.
- [Here is the C++ program](https://github.com/Szybet/inkbox/tree/toreader) I'm linking it against.

I'm completely lost with this. I tried other `[lib]` options and crate types with no change.

Comment: 2.4 was quite a while ago. You may have a very stale library in there somewhere.

Comment: @user4581301 The `GLIBC_2.4` symbol version merely means that the symbol was introduced or had its ABI changed in that version of glibc. It does not mean that glibc 2.4 is being used.

Comment: Looks like I need to do less embedded stuff and more big-boy OSes to get up to speed on their foibles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linux manual pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock_gettime.3.html)

> Link with `-lrt` (only for glibc versions before 2.17).

Your glibc version is 2.4, hence this instruction is good for your code.

Comment: This is basically the answer. The reason i wasn't able to resolve it was that i was using qmake and there are many ways to add -lrt, the one that worked was LIBS += -lrt - sadly i still have another problem, i created another question related to it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76967572/undefined-reference-to-sigsetjmp-in-rust-static-library-musl-build-with-openss

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors:

- The duplicate `rust_eh_personality` seems hard to fix properly with static linking (see e.g. https://github.com/mozilla/uniffi-rs/issues/1670 ), but adding `panic = "abort"` to the debug profile should work around it. In some sense, this is a symptom of linking parts of the Rust standard library twice into the final executable, which ought to work but is a bit wasteful.
- The error about `clock_gettime@@GLIBC_2.4` seems to be because at least some part of the code is actually using glibc instead of musl. Having both glibc and musl in the same process seems a bad idea at the least.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I have no other option